# jQuery slider, how to go back to beginning when last one is reached

Tags: jquery

Hi i've made a slider using jQuery, it works fine it has the functionality to go left and right however when it reaches the end it has no way of finding the start again and if I press prev from the start it wont go to the last entry.

I'm not particularly great with jQuery so don't have the knowledge to know what I should do next. Would appreciate if somebody could kindly point me in the right direction and perhaps give a brief explanation.

Thanks in advance

My code is below or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7w5t5/1/):

index.html

```
        <div class="bottom">  
                  <div class="rotatorarrows">
              <input type="hidden" id="currentShownDiva" value="1"/>
            <ul>
            <li><a class="parrows" id="parrowleft">Prev</a></li>
            <li><a class="parrows" id="parrowright">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="timeline_rotator">
        <!-- FIRST STORY -->
            <div class="contentrotator">
            <span class="news_element"><h2 class="timeline_year">2003</h2></span>
            <span class="news_element"><h3 class="timeline_heading">Apple Launches iPhone</h3>
            <p class="timeline_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p></span>
            </div>
                        <!-- FIRST STORY -->
            <div class="contentrotator">
            <span class="news_element"><h2 class="timeline_year">2004</h2></span>
            <span class="news_element"><h3 class="timeline_heading">Apple Launches iPhone</h3>
            <p class="timeline_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p></span>
            </div>
                        <!-- FIRST STORY -->
            <div class="contentrotator">
            <span class="news_element"><h2 class="timeline_year">2005</h2></span>
            <span class="news_element"><h3 class="timeline_heading">Apple Launches iPhone 2005</h3>
            <p class="timeline_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p></span>
            </div>


         </div>  <!-- End rotator-->
         </div> <!-- end bottom -->
```

js/js.js

// JavaScript Document

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.contentrotator').hide();
    $('.contentrotator:first').show();
    $('#parrowleft').off('click').on('click', function() {
        var currentView = parseInt($('#currentShownDiva').val(), 10) - 1;
        if (currentView < 1) return;
        $('.contentrotator').hide();
            $('.contentrotator:eq(' + (currentView - 1) + ')').show();
            $('#currentShownDiva').val(currentView);
    });

    $('#parrowright').off('click').on('click', function() {
        var currentView = parseInt($('#currentShownDiva').val(), 10) + 1;
        if (currentView > $('.contentrotator').length) return;
        $('.contentrotator').hide();
        $('.contentrotator:eq(' + (currentView -1) + ')').show();
        $('#currentShownDiva').val(currentView);

    });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, just check if your new index value is greater than the length of your content, and if so, set it to the first view. Likewise, if your new index is less than 1, set it to the length of your content.

```
$('.contentrotator').hide();
    $('.contentrotator:first').show();
    $('#parrowleft').off('click').on('click', function() {
        var currentView = parseInt($('#currentShownDiva').val(), 10) - 1;
        if (currentView < 1) {
            currentView = $('.contentrotator').length;
        }
        $('.contentrotator').hide();
            $('.contentrotator:eq(' + (currentView - 1) + ')').show();
            $('#currentShownDiva').val(currentView);
    });

    $('#parrowright').off('click').on('click', function() {
        var currentView = parseInt($('#currentShownDiva').val(), 10) + 1;
        if (currentView > $('.contentrotator').length) {
        currentView = 1;
        };
        $('.contentrotator').hide();
        $('.contentrotator:eq(' + (currentView -1) + ')').show();
        $('#currentShownDiva').val(currentView);

    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7w5t5/2/)